# How to add days in given datetime in Lua

Tags: datetime, lua

I am newbie in Lua scripting.my system is running on whatever timezone but I need my new date in gmt timezone and my given date also in gmt.

```
local creation_date = "2016-05-23 07:34:19"; //(This is in GMT date)

local yearValue, monthValue, dayValue,Hourvalue,Minutevalue,secondvalue = 
string.match(creation_date, '(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+) (%d+):(%d+):(%d+)')

dayValue, monthValue, yearValue,Hourvalue,Minutevalue,secondvalue = tonumber(dayValue), tonumber(monthValue), tonumber(yearValue),tonumber(Hourvalue),tonumber(Minutevalue),tonumber(secondvalue)

expiry_date = os.date("!%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",os.time{year = yearValue, month = monthValue, day = dayValue,hour = Hourvalue,minute =Minutevalue,second = secondvalue}+10*24*60*60)
```

Now whenever I am try to print expiry date it must need to print

```
   expiry_date ="2016-06-03 07:34:19" //(GIVEN DATE + 10 DAYS)
```

But instead of that is print like below

```
   expiry_date = "2016-06-13 12:00:00"// (Wrong Date)
```

I know in Lua have must functionality to print date in proper way as I needed but can't get from Google.

Comment: 10*60*60 is just 10 hours converted to seconds.

Comment: Okay that was my mistake let me add days instead of only hours but my question is not showing exact time like after 10 hours so must need to show like 2016-06-03 17:34:19 but that not get while i am execute above code any idea ? any suggestion ?

Comment: Please see the parameters to `os.time`: https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-os.time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice two things that could be causing problems, first `10*60*60` isn't 10 days in seconds, it's just 10 hours in seconds -- you probably want `10*24*60*60`. Second problem is that you're using the wrong fields for the `os.time`, the correct field to use is `hour`, `min` and `sec`.

For example,

```
local creation_date = "2016-05-23 07:34:19" -- (This is in GMT date)

local y, m, d, Hr, Min, Sec = creation_date:match '(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+) (%d+):(%d+):(%d+)'

local exp_sec = os.time
    { year = y, month = m, day = d,
      hour = Hr, min = Min, sec = Sec } + 10*24*60*60
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, let me try this

Comment: I have tried above code but still its giving me 5 hour difference. My real example answer of above code creation_date ='2017-01-04 08:14:17' and showing me  expiry_date= '2017-01-14 13:14:17'  instead expiry_date= '2017-01-14 08:14:17'

Comment: That `!` is converting to universal coordinate which might be messing up the printed time. Try modifying the date format to `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`.