# How to add days to a date generated by os.date() in Lua

Tags: lua

There is a lua function called `date()` in the `os` module. Calling `os.date()` will give the current date and time in the format: `Tue Aug 10 13:04:17 2021`.

Doing it like: `os.date("%x")` gives us the following: `08/10/21`.

Is it possible to manipulate the date function to add days to the current datetime/date returned? Something like what happens when you try to add days to a JavaScript date using `.setDate()` mutator. I've already had a look at [How to add days in given datetime in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458636/how-to-add-days-in-given-datetime-in-lua) but it's not what I want to achieve.

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `os.time` and compute with seconds:

```
t=os.time()
print(os.date("%c",t))
d=12
t=t+d*24*60*60
print(os.date("%c",t))
```

Answer (score 1):

Interactive with `io.read()`...

```
io.write('Input how many days should added>') print(os.date('%c',os.time({year=os.date('%Y'),month=os.date('%m'),day=tonumber(os.date('%d'))+tonumber(io.read()),hour=os.date('%H'),min=os.date('%M'),sec=os.date('%S')})))
```

A negative number also working.
...and also what day is in 365 days later ;-)
...and of course no error or exception handling (i.e. no input, hit only RETURN)
...even a `float` will fail, number has to be an `integer`

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Lua allows for working with table representations of the date with both `os.date` and `os.time`. This easily allows for a full range of date manipulations by adding/subtracting from year, month, day, etc.

For example, this shows how to subtract 200 days from a date:

```
s1 = os.time()
x1 = os.date('*t',s1)

x1.day = x1.day - 200
x1.isdst = nil -- this prevents DST time changes

s2 = os.time(x1)
print(s1, os.date("%c", s1))
print(s2, os.date("%c", s2))
--[[ output
1690299117  Tue Jul 25 11:31:57 2023
1673022717  Fri Jan  6 11:31:57 2023
]]
```

From the [os.date docs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.date), you can get a table result by using format `'*t'`

```
x1 = os.date('*t')
--[[ output:
x1 = {  year = 2023,  month = 7,  day = 25,
  hour = 11,  min = 17,  sec = 22,
  yday = 106,  wday = 1,  isdst = true }
]]
```

Note that `os.date` returns `isdst`. This value will be used by `os.time`, so if you don't want gaining/losing an hour, you need to set it to `nil`, as in the example above.

[os.time docs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.time) say:

> This table must have fields year, month, and day, and may have fields hour (default is 12), min (default is 0), sec (default is 0), and isdst (default is nil). Other fields are ignored.

> When the function is called, the values in these fields do not need to be inside their valid ranges. For instance, if sec is -10, it means 10 seconds before the time specified by the other fields; if hour is 1000, it means 1000 hours after the time specified by the other fields.